# Lucene 4.10: Indexing a Field to obtain faster access

Tags: lucene

I'm building a Lucene index made of document containing three field each ("one", "two" and "three").

When I'm going to query this index, I'll need to search for terms matching the one I searched only in two field of the three contained in each document (let's say, "one" and "three").

Is there a way to index those two fields obtain this in the building phase?

I know that I can specify in what fields the query should search, but I need to increase query speed.

Thank you

Comment: Sure you can combine the two into one field.  Trivially, really.  Just concatenate them and index them in a indexed-only (unstored) field.  Is there some aspect of your question I'm missing here?

Comment: you want to search by first and third field? did i understand you correctly?

Comment: I noticed that I did not write my question very well. What I need to do is perform a set of query. Let's say that I have 3 documents:

<x, a, b> <y, c, d> <x, z, y>

and I need to query it like this:

- search for "b" in the third fields of every document (in the example, I want to get "x" as a result)
- search for "d" in the third fields of every document (in the example, I want to get "y" as a result)
- search for "x" in the first field AND "y" in the third field of a document (in the example, I get <x, z, y> as a result).

Is there a way to improve the speed of this?

Comment: @femtoRgon I've actually tried this in my project but then rolled it back. This inflated the index size too much (I had to store positions as well).